# GeoServer MVT vector tile attributes

Tags: geoserver, features, vector-tiles, tile-map-service

I am serving MVT vector tiles from GeoServer through its TMS api and I can't find a way to add feature attributes.

When I try to add these attributes in the edit layer/data tab, I get an error "The CQL source expression for attribute name refers to attributes unavailable in the data source".

I am currently using a Mbtiles file as data source (through the Mbtiles plugin), the attributes are visible when I open this source with maptiler Engine and I have checked that the attributes are listed in the metadata table with a SQLite client.

Out of ideas, I have even added a schema for the WFS service thinking that there could be some kind of relation between WFS and TMS!

Is there a way to add these attributes or is this a GeoServer limitation or maybe a bug in the plugin?

Comment: where are you trying to add the attributes? TMS doesn't provide an edit operation

Comment: Just checked again with a simpler server (mbtileserver) and my feature attributes are included in the MVt tiles received by my openlayers app.

Comment: So you are using MVT tiles packed into MBTiles database as input, and you want to output them also as MVT tiles through GeoServer?

Comment: @ian-turton, I am trying to add these attributes in the "Data" tab of the "Edit layer" page. Since this page seems to be generic, I was hoping that it could apply to TMS...

Comment: @user30184, yes, exactly. I am trying this as a lightweight way to serve vector tiles with a specific (and limited) set of data extracted from OSM.

Comment: The reading is done with https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/mbtiles/input.html and by the error message "The CQL source expression for attribute name refers to attributes unavailable in the data source" GeoServer has some trouble in reading attributes from the source. It is searching for some attribute but it does not find it from the source data. Could it be that your styles are defined to use attributes which are not included in your limited set of data? I apologize, I have not used vector tiles as source myself so I am only guessing.

Comment: As far as I understand, a Mbtiles file is a SQLite database with two tables. One of them, contains metadata and one of its lines includes a list of layers and, for each layer, a list of fields. I had been assuming that the extension which is using the Mbtiles file as a store would be using this information but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Did you enable attribute customization by any chance? If so, please try to remove it. Also, the MBTiles data store is there so that one can take vector tiles stored in it, and serve WMS PNG images out of it. It's not really meant to be used for anything else, the store has no ability to put back toghether the polygons that were cut to make tiles, and it's not really an efficient way to re-serve those tiles (the code would unpack them into database like records, just to pack them again in MVT).

Comment: I have tried both with and without attribute customization enabled. I am aware of the limitations of MBTiles data stores and I am trying to use this to visualize OSM POIs and hiking tracks (with their metadata) as a layer on top of raster tiles which are missing this information. Vector tiles are handy to use for this since features are added and removed to match the map extent and that seems easier (and less stressful for the server) than, for instance, querying an overpass API to feed a vector layer. Am I following a wrong path?